# macOS Sierra: __textcoal__nt is deprecated

Tags: c++, xcode, g++, macos-sierra

I am still battling these annoying warnings when compiling C++ code on macOS Sierra:

```
warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
```

There are other pages discussing this issue: 
[warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecate since updating to Mac OSX Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865367/warning-section-textcoal-nt-is-deprecate-since-updating-to-mac-osx-sierra); [Xcode 8 warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692973/xcode-8-warning-section-textcoal-nt-is-deprecated); [Disable assembler warning ".section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38193043/disable-assembler-warning-section-text-textcoal-nt-coalesced-pure-instruct).

However, this issue has yet to be resolved and these posts are all several months old.  This is something that I would really love to get fixed as I hate seeing these warnings every time I compile C++ code--even though they can be safely ignored (reference: https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/09/22/compiling-gcc-6-macos/).

If there is still no solution, is there anything that I can do to increase the priority of the need for fixing this issue that is affecting many C++ developers on macOS Sierra?

I am using GNU gcc/g++ v5.3 compilers with Xcode 8.2.1 on macOS Sierra.  I have attempted all suggested solutions I have found, for example, setting the path:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```

and still cannot resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an oldest compiler, you can try figure out when it became deprecated by seeing the previous versions of GCC. Take a look at here: https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will look through the site you provided.  However, it would nice to use the most recent stable release of gcc/g++ on macOS Sierra.

Comment: Sure. But if it is deprecated you should try to look for the update on macOS Sierra. Probably there is some better way to do it know. Good luck!